# R Left join and copy several rows by identifier variable

Tags: r

I want to combine several rows in a data frame by an identifier variable and paste them together. Here a minimal example.

```
id  val1 val2
1   a     d
1   a     d
2   b     e
2   b     e
3   c     f
3   c     f
```

I want that my final data frame looks like this.

```
id val11 val12 val21 val22 
1  a     a     d     d
2  b     b     e     e
3  c     c     f     f
```

Thank you in advance

```
id<-c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
val1<-c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
val2<-c("d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f")
df<-cbind(id, val1, val2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a sequence column by 'id' and then use that in `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(id)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c('val1', 'val2'), names_sep = "")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     id val11 val12 val21 val22
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 a     a     d     d    
#2     2 b     b     e     e    
#3     3 c     c     f     f
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id, val1, val2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
#Code
df <- as.data.frame(df)
#Transform
new <- df %>% pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  group_by(id,name) %>%
  mutate(name=paste0(name,row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    val11 val21 val12 val22
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     a     d     a     d    
2 2     b     e     b     e    
3 3     c     f     c     f
```

Which in some sense is quite similar to **@akrun** answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option with `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df), id ~ rowidv(df, "id"), value.var = c("val1", "val2"))
```

gives

```
   id val1_1 val1_2 val2_1 val2_2
1:  1      a      a      d      d
2:  2      b      b      e      e
3:  3      c      c      f      f
```